# show only a fixed number of entries of a table - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I've a module (named Brèves) and in the index I need to be showed to columns: the first one shows only entries with an image; the second one shows entries without image. the thing is that I only want to be show the last 4 entries in each column. How can I do it? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Symfony is a web application framework written in PHP which follows the [model-view-controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) paradigm.**

**Your controller:**

In your action:

```
 // Action (controller) - apps/frontend/modules/youmudule/actions/actions.class.php

   public function executeName(sfWebRequest $request)
     {

       $this->entries = Doctrine_Core::getTable('YouTableName') ->getEntry();

     }
```

**Your model:**
Plase where you put all your "query"

```
// Model - lib/model/doctrine/YourtablenameTable.class.php

    public function getEntry()
      {
        $q = $this->createQuery('a')
                  ->addORDERBY ('created_at DESC')
                  ->limit(4);

    return $q->execute();
  }
```

**Your view:**

```
 // apps/frontend/modules/youmudule/templates/nameSuccess.php

  <?php foreach ($entries  as $entry): ?>

        $entry->getSomeData()

  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**Read this [tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/)**

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a bit new at symfony... what is the model? can you explain me the code you wrote ? thank you